# Blackjack game not updating hands each time everyone draws

Tags: python, function, variables, blackjack

I'm trying to make a simple text-based Python game around blackjack. The game knows the variable 'hand' and 'd_hand' which are your hand and the dealer's hand, but won't update it after each new card is drawn. hand and d_hand are assigned to a random integer between 1 and 11 plus your current hand before it added the random number, which in theory should mean that your hand updates itself every time a new card is drawn.
Here's the code:

```
def draw(hand, d_hand):
x = randint(1, 11)
card = x
hand = x + hand
print("You drew...")
print(card)
y = randint(1, 11)
d_card = y
d_hand = y + d_hand
print("Dealer drew...")
print(d_card)
print("Your hand: ")
print(hand)
print("Dealer's hand: ")
print(d_hand)
ask()
```

And here's the output of everything:
(Note: I only am showing one function here, the game is obviously more than just this one function I'm showing.)

```
Press enter to begin: 
You drew...
1
Dealer drew...
5
Your hand: 
1
Dealer's hand: 
5
Hit or stay? (h/s): h
You drew...
10
Dealer drew...
8
Your hand: 
10
Dealer's hand: 
8
Hit or stay? (h/s): '''
```

I'm not really sure what the issue is here...

By the way, I'm new to this site so I can't like any comments, so thank you to everyone who answered!

Comment: `hand` and `d_hand` are local variables which cease to exist when function ends.

Comment: Hello Matty, to expand upon Micheal's statement about "local variables" please take a look at the term "scope". It is used in all programming languages and is a way to organize code and keep variables from being accessed inappropriately. I've found a resource about this here. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `hand` and `d_hand` are lists (or mutable objets),

you may want to update the object itself by replacing `hand = x + hand` with `hand.append(x)`.

Otherwise, your code will just create a new local list `hand` that will be lost when the function ends.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted it looks like you aren't returning the new hands. So when the function returns the hands will revert to whatever value they were before the call. You can return tulples in python like `return (hand,d_hand)` and then do something like `hand,d_hand = draw(hand,d_hand)`